Why is the iCloud given name not being fetched?
The iCloud-Givenname is not retrieved. Instead, ‘Name not available’ is always displayed. There is no other error message. Is the Apple-ID-Name the same as the iCloud-Name? Here ist the related code:
private func discoverIcloudUser(id: CKRecord.ID)  {
        CKContainer.default().fetchUserRecordID { (record, error) in
            CKContainer.default().fetchShareParticipant(withUserRecordID: id) { (userID, error) in DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let name = userID?.userIdentity.nameComponents?.givenName {
                    self.givenName = name
                } else {
                    self.errorHistory.append("Name not available.")
                }
                
                
                if let error = error {
                    self.error = error.localizedDescription
                    self.errorHistory.append(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
                
            }
        }
    }

I have an iCloud account with both ‘Givenname’ and ‘Familyname’ filled in. I have also tried to request other names such as ‘SuffixName’ without success.
I really hope someone here can help me. Kind regards Jamie
